# Неправильный вывод при умножении данных типа double на long

Tags: java, netbeans

Значение Current Asia Population выводится с буквой Е и равно 4.2E9
Как исправить?

```
public class Casting02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        long currentWorldPop = 7_000_000_000L;
        System.out.println("Current World Population: " +currentWorldPop);

        //World population in 1950,  Source: United Nations Population Division
        //2.52 Billion
        int africaPop   =   221_000_000;
        long asiaPop     =  1_402_000_000;
        int europePop   =   547_000_000;
        int americasPop =   339_000_000;
        int oceanaPop   =    13_000_000;
        System.out.println("World Population in 1950: " 
                +(africaPop +asiaPop +europePop +americasPop +oceanaPop));

        //The current population of Asia is an estimated 60% of the world population

        double percentAsia =0.6;
        double currentAsiaPop  =currentWorldPop * percentAsia;
        System.out.println("Current Asia Population: " +currentAsiaPop);      

    }  
}
```